# How to fix Tree view all Product showing for a user?

Tags: python, list, view, tree, odoo

**I have created a table to store some product informations**

I need to show the product view in tree,form view. but the problem is the products showing for all company users. i just want to show the product only for the company user. but it's showing for other company users too.

**Model**

```
class RiceProcurement(models.Model):
    _name = 'rice.procurement'
    _description = 'Rice procurement quantity manage table'

    product_select = fields.Many2one('product.template', String='Subsidised Rice', required=True,
                                     domain="[('item_type', '=', 'rice'),"
                                            "('subsidy_type_purchase', '=', 'subsidised'),('uom_id','=',3)]")
    
    product_qty = fields.Float(string='Quantity (in Kg)', digits='Product Unit of Measure', required=True)
    company_id = fields.Many2one('res.company',
                                 string='Company',
                                 required=True,
                                 default=lambda self: self.env.user.company_id.id)
    supplier_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string='Supplier', required=True)
    date_approve = fields.Datetime('Confirmation Date', default=lambda self: fields.Datetime.now(),
                                   index=True, copy=False)
```

**Tree view**

```
<record id="rice_procurement_tree_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">rice.procurement.tree.view</field>
        <field name="model">rice.procurement</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Rice Procurement" import="0">
                <field name="product_select" domain="[('company_id','=',company_id)]"/>
                <field name="date_approve" string="Date"/>
                <field name="product_qty" sum="Total Quantity"/>
                <field name="company_id" invisible="1"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>
```

**ir.act.Window**

```
    <record id="rice_procurement_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Rice procurement</field>
            <field name="res_model">rice.procurement</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">list</field>
            <field name="domain">[('company_id','=',company_id)]</field>
    </record>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Do you want a single user per product? Do you mean the current, logged-in user, or something else? Is `company_id` your user? What does your data structure look like?

Comment: @ConnorLow I think his project is multi-company and the products from one company are shown to alls users from all company and he doesn't want that?

Answer (score 0):

A record rule is there already which is added by the Odoo. Go to Settings -> General Settings, then if you scroll down in the multi-company you can see two options, one is Common Contact Book and other is Common Product Catalog.

By default these two boolean fields will be ticked, in your case, you can untick  Common Product Catalog.

Once you untick this a record rule named  Product multi-company will visible in Settings -> Technical -> Security -> Record Rules, which was initially set as active as False.

See the [rule](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/11.0/addons/product/security/product_security.xml) in this File:

[reference](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/how-keep-the-record-rules-to-see-only-the-produtc-of-the-particular-company-159365)

Answer (score 0):

**Finally I have created a role in my module, now it's working**

inside security folder created a custom role file to fix the issue

```
<record id="rice_procurement_company_rule" model="ir.rule">
     <field name="name">Rice Procurement</field>
     <field ref="model_rice_procurement" name="model_id"/>
     <field name="domain_force">[('company_id','in',company_ids)]</field>
     <field name="global" eval="True"/>
</record>
```